# What does the word 「ぶったてる」mean?

Tags: words, prefixes

What does the word 「ぶったてる」mean?

> このドヤがいの西{にし}のはずれにりっぱな総{そう}合{ごう}病{びょう}院{いん}を**ぶったてる**こと!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

「ぶったてる」＝「ぶっ建{た}てる」

= "**to build**" or rather "**to f***ing build**" if one were to translate the nuance intended.

「ぶっ」 is a manly and slangy **verb prefix** that emphasizes the meaning of the verb.  The core meaning of the verb itself stays the same even if the prefix is added.

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%89%93%E3%81%A3-618986#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

Related verb prefixes for emphasis:

「おっ」、「かっ」、「つっ」、「つん」、「とっ」、「ひっ」、「ひん」、「ぶち」、「ぶん」、「ふっ」, etc.  There might be a few more.

Comment: What sort of surprises me about this usage compared to usual usages (like those listed as examples in the dictionary entry) is that 建てる doesn't feel like something that is normally done "in fury" (which is my best attempt at trying to articulate the similarity of the verbs I feel like I usually see ぶっ used with).

Comment: "Doing something in fury" would surely be one implied nuance that these prefixes give, but it is not the only nuance they can express.  In many cases, you could just call it 'tough guy's lively street speech'.  The extra syllable with a small っ sound at the top gives a rhythm that we just "like" as does the samll っ generally does in informal speech.

Comment: "Sound" is a far more important feature of Japanese than J-learners might realize until they get to your level.  Just look at all those endless onomatopoeias.  With Japanese having been a spoken language for the majority of its history, it still strongly maintains the characteristics of one.  Loose distinction between direct and indirect speech is another example.   Quotative と without a verb to go with is yet another.

Comment: @Darius It might be helpful to know that it derives from 打ち建てる and this prefix 打ち adds nuance of "suddenly" or "tidbit".