# What does the word 「たたっ」 mean?

Tags: words, prefixes

I'm not sure if it means "very long time" in this sentence.　If it means that, what does the 「っ」 do in the sentence?

ジョーのやろうは刑{けい}務{む}所{しょ}へ**たたっ**こまれるようなことになるんでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the passive of たたっこむ, which is an elided form of 叩き込む, which here figuratively means 'to throw someone in prison'. Thus a translation might be:

> That bastard Joe, could it be that he's going to end up getting thrown in prison?

Comment: So what is the meaning or nuance of 「たたっ/たたき」 by itself?

Comment: @l'électeur Why don't you link to [your answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24578/1628) yourself (and maybe spare yourself the downvote). This way jogloran would know to include this information in this answer and any future answer he might post. Your answer would also be listed as first source for this explanation across several answers.