# What does the word 「ぶっぱたく」 mean?

Tags: words, verbs, manga, prefixes

A little girl who said the following sentence holding a geta in her hand is angry that officers not allow her and her friends to go inside a place.

> ひいきしやがると**ぶっぱたく**ぞっ。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the prefix ぶっ (deriving from 打つ【ぶつ】) applied to the verb はたく (叩く) "to knock/hit". (For details, see [your other question about ぶったてる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24577/1628).)