# What does "ぶっ飛ぶ" mean?

Tags: manga

> 相性がよければいいほどブッ飛ぶよ？

I don't understand the meaning of "ぶっ飛ぶ" in this sentence. After searching on Jisho I found "lack common sense" or "be extremely surprised" is that it ?

[image]

Comment: Related: [What does the word 「ぶっぱたく」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38543/what-does-the-word-ぶっぱたく-mean) Does this help you to understand the plot of your manga?

Comment: It is impossible to answer without more context. What characters are they, what are they talking about, and what does 堕天 mean in this story?

Comment: They talk about how angels become fallen angels by falling in love with humans.

Comment: That's a big hint (now I can at least exclude the possibility that they're talking about a golf club), but the context is still lacking. What's the sentence right before this? Can you paste the entire page? By any chance, are they talking about something related to drug or sex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since he seems to be talking about something related to pleasant sensations, this ぶっ飛ぶ should mean "to trip", "to reach ecstasy", "to get extremely high", "to come" or something along these lines. ぶっ is an intensifier, and one of the slangy meanings of 飛ぶ is "to (almost/temporarily) lose consciousness/memory".

As slang, ぶっ飛ぶ can also mean:

- to be blown away (e.g., by a live performance)
- to lack common sense; outlandish (personality, style, etc)

  > - 彼の考え方はぶっ飛んでいる
  > - [電波系](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denpa_song)のぶっ飛んだ曲