# What is the meaning of 壊れる when referring to a person?

Tags: meaning, words, verbs

Context: a mangaka is talking about a character of a manga who is a psychopathic killer called Crazy Rascal.

> そのネーミングに関しては、僕が個人的に尊敬している、とある“プロ”の方のあだ名？からいただきました。ご本人は当然こんなに**ぶっ壊れていません**のでご注意を。

What is the meaning of ぶっ壊れている in this context? Does it mean "to be crazy", "to have something wrong in the head"? If my interpretation is correct, why is there ご注意を at the end even though the verb is negative? My translation attempt:

> About that name, I took it from the nickname of a certain "professional" I personally respect. This person is not that crazy of course, so be careful (?).

Also, could you explain why is there a question mark before から? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.  「壊{こわ}れる」, when used to talk about a person, means "***to break down mentally***", "***to go bonkers***", etc.

「ぶっ」 is an emphatic and manly verb prefix, which is exlained here:

[What does the word 「ぶったてる」mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24577/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%b6%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b-mean/24578#24578)

「ご注意{ちゅうい}を」, in this context, does not really mean "Be careful!".  It should be interpreted as a light kind of "Please be advised."  One could even say that the phrase is used almost as light humor rather than a serious warning.

Finally, the question mark following 「あだ名{な}」 would suggest that the name in question may or may not actually be called his "official" nickname.  The author is using the word 「あだ名」 loosely here.