# What does the で do in this phrase?

Tags: translation, particle-で

I'm trying to translate this phrase:
「全ての生物をブッチ切りで超越したのだ！。」
which I believe roughly comes out to be:
"I have surpassed all living beings!"

My question is: how is で used in this sentence? It is preceded by the noun, according to Jishou, 「ブッチ切り」, which means "to establish a large lead above one's competitors". After the particle is ちょうえつ, meaning "to transcend". Since they both have similar meanings, I am confused about how the particle で connects the two in a sentence.

Comment: `ブッチ切り` -- ん？ ぶっちぎり came from ブッ+ちぎり(千切る), not ブッチ+きり(切る)...

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24577/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%b6%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b-mean/24578#24578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「ぶっちぎり」 would usually be written in hiragana instead of mix of katakana and kanji. And it is a very casual word (in the sense it should not be used in any formal occasions).

So as you mentioned, 「ぶっちぎり」somewhat means 'exceed by far', and 「超越」
means 'transcend' in formal translation. When you connect these two together with で, 「ぶっちぎり」becomes an adjective for 「超越」. Thus even if you remove 「ぶっちぎりで」from the sentence it makes perfect sense. So in English

> 'to transcend **by far**'

the bold part would be the equivlant of 「ぶっちぎりで」