# Understanding "これだから……は"?

Tags: grammar, structure

> 寿季「雨星か。そういやお前も参加してたんだっけか」
>
> 結菜「ちょっとちょっと、元相棒のことをおざなりにしすぎじゃないですかー」
>
> 寿季「今今回は一般参加者として参加しないからリサーチしてなかったんだよ」
>
> 結菜「わたしの垢をフォローしてたら嫌でも目にするんじゃないんですかー」
>
> 寿季「ほら、俺って2千人ぐらいフォローしてるから」
>
> 結菜「はー、**これだから知り合いだけをみれるリスト作らない人は**」
>
> 寿季「分かった分かった。帰ったらリストを作って**ぶち込んで**おくよ」

This is a conversation between 寿季 and his old partner 雨星結菜.

Is "これだから……は" kind of a fixed structure? And how should I understand the structure?

By the way, what does ぶち込む mean in this context?

Comment: Highly related （ぶち込む）: 　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24577/what-does-the-word-%e3%81%b6%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8b-mean

Comment: "That's why people like you who don't create a separate list of friends and acquaintances are so..." "Okay! Okay! When I get back I will make that list."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, これだからXは is a set expression. It literally means "Because of this, X ...!" and the omitted predicate is usually something negative. It implies "This is why I don't like X", "This is why X sucks", etc. (On rare occasions, a positive predicate is implied, so you have to always see the context.)

ぶちこむ is a strong and rough version of 入れる. It means putting 結菜's account in the newly created list. It's normally rude to say アカウントをリストにぶち込む. He said this probably because he was reluctant or frustrated.